# Get specific word from attributes.id.value.replace

Tags: javascript, html

I have this variable that make an replace to get the number from a button created dynamic.his is the whole id: btn-load-more-sectors_149

```
let cdUnit = e.target.attributes.id.value.replace('btn-load-more-sectors_', '');
```

The result if the code that come from back end is 149.

Now I want to take just the word sectors, and i tried this way..

```
let buttonId = e.target.attributes.id.value.replace('btn-load-more-', '', '_' + cdUnit );
```

but the result on the console.log is sectors_149
How do I take just the word sectors? Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output? are you console.logging buttonId

Comment: Yes, i'm. The result on console is sectors_149

Comment: I updated my question with some infos

Comment: Do you want  to get  only  words  from  your ```e.target.attributes.id.value```??

Comment: Yes, only the word 'sectors'

Comment: e.target.attributes.id.value.split('-').pop().split('_')[0];

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much.